# Jquery add class if a element exists within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want Jquery to add a class `.pointer` to `.staff-container` if `<a href="">` exists within `.staff-picture`.

**My Jquery:**

```
if($('.staff-container').find('.staff-picture').closest('a').length) {
    $(this).addClass('pointer');
}
```

No class is being added with the above jquery, what am I doing wrong?

---

---

**My Css:**

```
.pointer {
    cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="teachers">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="scroll transparent">
            <div class="staff-outer-container">
                <div class="staff-container">
                    <div class="staff">
                        <div class="staff-picture">
                            <a href="http://ahmedmathematics.weebly.com/index.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/people/teachers/ahmed.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <p><span class="bold">Mr. Ahmed</span><br />
                        Ext. 13417<br />
                        Room 417/323<br />
                        <a href="mailto:Ahmed@wcskids.net">Ahmed@wcskids.net</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="staff-container">
                    <div class="staff">
                        <div class="staff-picture">
                            <img src="img/people/teachers/aiello.png" />
                        </div>
                        <p><span class="bold">Mr. Aiello</span><br />
                        Ext. 13328<br />
                        Room 328/323<br />
                        <a href="mailto:ASusan@wcskids.net">ASusan@wcskids.net</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="staff-container">
                    <div class="staff">
                        <div class="staff-picture">
                            <a href="http://www.mraiosa.com/class/Home.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/people/teachers/aiosa.png" /></a>
                        </div>
                        <p><span class="bold">Mr. Aiosa</span><br />
                        Ext. 13419<br />
                        Room 419/323<br />
                        <a href="mailto:BAiosa@wcskids.net">BAiosa@wcskids.net</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this `!important` ? If your CSS code is well managed you very rarely need this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('.staff-picture a').closest('.staff-container').addClass('pointer');
```

I hope the logic is obvious from the code.

Answer (score 3):

I would first iterate through the `.staff-container` divs, then use a conditional to determine which ones have an `a` tag using the `this` object as context:

```
//Goes through all the .staff-picture divs
$('.staff-container').each(function(){

    //If the a tag exists within the current .staff-picture (returned object isn't undefined)
    if($('a', this).html() != undefined){

        //Add the class if a exists
        $(this).addClass('pointer'); 
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9ZKG/

### EDIT

Sorry, I meant staff-container, not staff-picture. But, either will work.

### 2nd EDIT

Also, if you are curious why your original methodology wasn't working, it is because the conditional you use (the first `if`) does not instantiate the `this` object. That is, `this` does not exist inside your function.

Comment: In my case pretty similar to the question here, this worked just perfectly! Had to dig up `<br />` tags from divs and set a custom class with `line-height` attribute for a more fixed view of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $selector = $('.staff-container');
if($selector.find('.staff-picture').has('a')) {
    $selector.addClass('pointer');
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the if I believe. You can just do $('.staff-container').find('.staff-picture').has('a').addClass('pointer')

Comment: @ryanulit That would add the class to `staff-picture` not `staff-container`

Answer (score 1):

`$.closest()` traverses *up* not down the tree, therefore you are not finding anything. [see the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Oh, if that's the case then you can modify my answer below to be as follows: $('.staff-picture a').closest('staff-container').addClass('pointer);

Answer (score 0):

I like to approach these types of problems with "reverse" logic:

```
$('.staff-picture a').parent().parent().parent().addClass('pointer);
```

There's probably a way to "choose" your `staff-container` parent, but if the DOM structure doesn't change, this works great.

This starts by selecting all the a-links and then ONLY applies those up which uses jQuery's powerful selection code. It doesn't rely on tests with if-statements.